# Call a function in Python and pass only the arguments it expects

Tags: python

How do I call a function and only pass it the arguments that it expects. For example say I have the following functions:

```
func1 = lambda a: True
func2 = lambda a, b: True
func3 = lambda c: True
```

I want some Python code that is able to successfully call these functions without raising a `TypeError` by passing unexpected arguments. i.e.

```
kwargs = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
for func in (func1, func2, func3):
    func(**kwargs)  # some magic here
```

I'm not interested in just adding `**kwargs` to the functions when I define them.

Comment: @BlaXpirit... and bruteforce all combinations of arguments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `inspect.getargspec()`:

```
from inspect import getargspec
kwargs = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3)
for func in (func1, func2, func3):
    func(**dict((name, kwargs[name]) for name in getargspec(func)[0]))
```

Comment: Note it is deprecated since 3.0 Use getfullargspec() instead, which provides information about keyword-only arguments and annotations. but getfullargspec() is not available in 2.7 and lower

Answer (score 4):

Well, depending on exactly what you will want to do with variable arguments and keyword arguments, the result will be a little different, but you probably want to start with `inspect.getargspec(func)`.